# Memory settings with MacTeX - Which texmf.cnf to modify

Tags: mactex, texmf

I have some problems to understand how to manage memory for LaTeX.
I use the [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/downloading.html) 2011 distribution with no modifications (cad only with TeXLive 2011).

I have searched a lot on internet and on this very good forum (which have similar topics).
Anyway all the things I have found and tested do not have worked.

I suppose the file I should modify is the one located on this path:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
```

Originally this file contains:

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf
TEXMFVAR = ~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG = ~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-config
```

Then at the end of this file I should write my modifications (ex: `buf_size = 250000`).

Anyway this don't seems to work (as error log say me that `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [buffer size=200000]`). If the modification were working I would get 250000 instead of 200000.

I have also tested to place a `texmf.cnf` into `~/Library/texmf` or `~/Library/texlive/2011` or `~/texmf/mytexcnf/texmf.cnf` (as suggered in Manual for Package pgfplots) and other similar paths 
Finally I tried to type `texhash` or `fmtutil --all` on the terminal but again without success.

I think I'm totally lost and I would greatly appreciate the assistance of experts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you need to increase the capacity? What is giving you the error?

Comment: It is a graph TikZ extracted from matlab (with matlab2tikz). Perhaps the graph has a problem but I want to test increase some memories options. Even if this graph is broken, knowing how to change memory settings will be necessary for me as I have many graphs to convert. The problem is not the number of graphs as I have already use the options to externally compile the TikZ graphics (`\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} \usepgfplotslibrary{external} \tikzexternalize[prefix=myfigures/]`) but that I know that I will have some heavy TikZ graphics to compile. Thanks

Comment: Your file compiles with no error on a standard MacTeX installation (OS 10.6.8; 4GB memory).

Comment: Really ? It is so strange ... I have the latest MacTeX 2011 with 0S 10.6.8 and 8GB. Which editor do you use ? Do you use pdflatex or latex->dvi->pdf ?

Comment: Also, the log file you included in the archive isn't actually the log, it's the output of the console (which isn't quite the same.) Can you upload the actual log file itself?

Comment: I'm using TeXShop and pdflatex. But there's no difference if I compile from the commandline.

Comment: I have updated the file with some other logs from different editors.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To change the memory allocation you should edit `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf`. On a Mac, these are files owned by the system, and you can't edit them without authenticating as an administrative user.

There are two ways to do this.  If you are comfortable with a command line editor such as vi, emacs, pico or nano (all standardly installed in the MacOS) you can use one of these editors to edit the file.  To do so you invoke the editor using `sudo` from an admin account. (Example below, using `emacs`).

```
sudo emacs /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
```

You will be prompted for your password.

If you are not familiar with any of these editors, and would prefer to do this from the regular GUI interface, you can use a good text editor such as the free [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) which will allow you to save system files after authenticating.  To do this from the finder, you can do the following:

- In the Go menu, choose Go to Folder
- Enter `/usr/local/texlive/2011/`
- Control-click on `texmf.cnf` and choose Open with, then select TextWrangler

Now you can edit the file, and when you save it, TextWrangler will authenticate you.

To increase the main memory to e.g. 7000000 add the line:

```
main_memory = 7000000
```

After you modify `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf` you need to run

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

This should rebuild the formats with the new values.

It is important that you run `sudo fmtutil-sys` and NOT `fmtutil`.

If you have previously run `fmtutil` by mistake, you should remove the following folder from your *local* Library (i.e. ~/Library/)

```
~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var
```

You can do this by navigating to the `~/Library/texlive/2011/` folder and dragging the `texmf-var` folder to the trash. Alternatively, from the command line you can type:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var
```

Of course, if you have existing things in this directory you should not delete all of it, just the `web2c` directory inside it:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/web2c
```

Comment: I have tested your command but it didn't have worked. I just have uploaded a file by editing my question. If you have some time can you try compiling it before and after modifying your memory settings (for example: `main_memory = 7000000` or `buf_size = 250000`). Even if it don't work, you will be able to see if a change appears between your two logs. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, if I edit `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf` and then run this command (note the `-sys` part), the memory is correctly changed.  If you ran `fmtutil` (without the `-sys`) this may be causing the problem.

Comment: I Have run your command again without success but previously (before to post my question) I ran `fmtutil --all`. Do you think I should uninstall MacTeX and then reinstall it ? \\ Also to edit the file `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf` I have set access read/write for me for the file and its folder 2011. Maybe it not the correct way to do that. How do you edit this file ?

Comment: I don't think you need to reinstall anything, but you do need to fix the potential problem you created by running `fmtutil` and not `fmtutil-sys`.  To do this, you should delete the folder `~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var`. (This is the one in your *home* library). To edit the file in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf` you need to open the file with an editor like TextWrangler that allows you to edit protected files after asking for your password, or use an editor from the command line and invoke the editor with `sudo ...` But I really don't think that memory is the source of your problems.

Comment: It seems with some more testing that memory *is* the problem.  I've updated my answer with some more specific steps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works now. Your help has been invaluable and I thank you. For others, if you need to change your LateX memory settings, I confirm that Allan's instructions are the good ones.

Comment: Note: I had to add the appropriate bin folder to my path to successfully execute `fmtutil-sys`. With my (old) distribution that was `PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin/"`

Comment: I too have a large PGF file that does not compile. Changed the `texlive\2013\texmf.cnf` file for save size = 160000 and ran `fmutil-sys -all`, but still pdflatex is throwin the same error for save size over 80000 as before. This is under Windows though.

Comment: @AlanMunn: +1.  But I wouldn’t recommend removing the whole directory `~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/`: users might have other items saved there, besides custom formats, that they might not want to delete (_e.g._, temporary fonts, custom documentation…).  I’d just tell them to remove `~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/web2c`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Thanks. That's a good point.

Comment: @anselm I rolled back your edit since the directory location has not been changed with current versions of MacTeX. Perhaps you are not using a Mac? Or you installed using the TeX Live installer instead of using the MacTeX installer?

Comment: For statistics: worked just fine. Thanks!