# How to increase bufsize for lualatex or pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, luatex, memory

I work with large TikZ graphics for which the default bufsize of lualatex/pdflatex is too small:

```
Unable to read an entire line---bufsize=200000.
Please increase buf_size in texmf.cnf.
```

Is there a quick way to increase the buffer size for either lualatex or pdflatex *without* editing texmf.cnf?

If there is no quick solution, could someone please describe the obscure configuration mechanism of LaTeX that needs to be executed to process changes made to texmf.cf?

Also, where is texmf.cnf in a standard installation of a Ubuntu texlive package?
What happens to my changes to texmf.cf when I update the texlive package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To find the `texmf.cnf` of your installation, use `kpsewhich`:

```
kpsewhich texmf.cnf
```

In a normal installation of texlive this will point you to a file that will probably tell you not to edit any *other* `texmf.cnf`.

You could try to increase the `buf_size` for one run by setting it on the cmdline:

```
buf_size=100000 pdflatex foo.tex
```

This *may* work, but you may also have to change `texmf.cnf` and recreate the formats.

See also [Memory settings with MacTeX - Which texmf.cnf to modify](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24753/5763)

Comment: buf_size=100000 lualatex foo.tex worked for me. So it's just an environment variable. :-)

Comment: @BernhardAnderson: The settings in `texmf.cnf` can be overridden by environment variables.

Comment: @MartinSchröder How should I exactly buf_size=100000... in cmdline(windows)? because I get the error buf_size not an internal or external command