# Need help in LaTeX compilation

Tags: texlive, compiling, overleaf

I have a big issue with project compilation. Instead of "concentrating on getting the right content", I've spend several days on getting the project compiled. My project deadline is near, and I would appreciate any help.

I work with Overleaf and I liked its' interface and it is easy to use. I have a big project. I can compile it by parts, but I can't compile the whole project since Overleaf applies compilation time limitation even for paying customers. I tried all suggested tricks, but it didn't help:
[Fixing and preventing compile timeouts](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Fixing_and_preventing_compile_timeouts).

I've made an attempt to compile the project locally on my computer (Windows). I installed TeX Live. Again, I can compile the project by parts, but I can't compile the whole project. I receive the following error:

```
Unable to read an entire line---bufsize=200000.
Please increase buf_size in texmf.cnf.
```

I tried to increase the `buf_size` by running on the Windows cmd:

```
buf_size=100000 pdflatex main.tex
```

As proposed [in this StackExchange thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43430/how-to-increase-bufsize-for-lualatex-or-pdflatex)

But I get an error:

```
'buf_size' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Then, I changed `texmf.cnf` file by adding:

```
main_memory = 7000000
```

As proposed [in this StackExchange thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24753/memory-settings-with-mactex-which-texmf-cnf-to-modify).
But when I run in cmd:

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --all
```

I get the following error:

```
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have no idea how to compile the project. I worked on it for several months. I will appreciate any assistance.

Best regards,
Alex.

Comment: why does your project need such a large bufsize? Do you externalize large graphics?

Comment: `sudo` is a linux command do not use that on windows

Comment: is your entire file on one line? why do you need an input buffer of anything like that size?

Comment: just use `fmtutil-sys --all` (no `sudo`) but first check your tex coding that you are not in an infinite loop that will use up the buffer however large you make it.

Comment: It is a big project, about 500 pages. Yes I use a lot of graphics, but I am not able to compile it in Oveleaf's draft mode (without graphics).

Comment: you could normally process a document of thousands of pages with an input buffer of a few hundred characters, why are you producing (after expanding commands) 100000 characters _on a single line of input_ ???

Comment: Either way, follow David's comment "just use `fmtutil-sys --all`" --- post a follow-up if it doesn't work. It appears many people don't use Windows here

Comment: I tried `fmtutil-sys --all` but I get the same error after the compilation. What does it mean "a single line of input"? I think that I am missing something.

Comment: What does "same error" mean? Does the error message change to `buf_size=700000` instead?

Comment: It is very hard to get a valid tex source to run out of memory.  It is much more likely that you have some sort of error.  Are you sure you can compile each part?  I've compiled a 1000 page book locally with lots of TikZ and not had any trouble (other than the 5 minutes (I think) that I have to wait for each compilation).

Comment: the error is saying that (effectively) you have a single line of your source file that has 200 thousand characters. That's a _very_ long line. Some expansion constructs need to happen in line so the buffer usage can be longer than the line of the source file but it is always related to a single part of the document the length of the document does not matter, you have an effective _line_ in your source file that is longer than the buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the buffer size on the commandline

```
 pdflatex --cnf-line=buf_size=400000 file
```

would double the default size of 200000 to 400000.

You can check how much of the buffer is being used by checking a line at the end of the log

```
 35i,5n,50p,1016b,109s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,400000b,200000s
```

it is the `b` value here this test used 1016 (already a *very* abnormally large example created by having 1000 x on a single line)

Note this buffer is the buffer for holding a *single line* of input not for holding the whole file, it needs to be larger than the actual longest line in the source file, but not usually much larger, you have to be doing something unusual to use 200000 characters in the input buffer.

You may have an ininite loop that is filling this buffer no matter how large you make it. If you comment out parts of the document so that it completes you can check each section and check the `b` value to see which construct is using more than 200000 input buffer characters.

Comment: Thanks David, it solves the buffer size issue, but now the compilation is stacked with the following message: 
`[323] [324]
No file main.ind.
(./main.aux
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.1 ^^@
       ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@...

?`

Comment: On the other hand it compiled the first 326 pages, and this is a significant progress!

Comment: that is byte 0, ASCII null why have you got nulls in your aux file, but that is easy to fix just delete the aux file

Comment: oh that probably explains the buffer overrun if you have 200,000 null bytes then tex will see that as a single line with 200 thousand characters and over run the buffer. As said in comments under the question fixing the error makes more sense than increasing the buffer size @ab3001

Comment: David, what are "null bytes" and how to find them? I want to find the error and fix it.

Comment: every character in a computer corresponds to a number, but the number 0 is not normally used as a character it is used for special purposes, languages like C for example use position 0 to denote the end of a string. Your `.aux` file just consists of multiple  bytes of 0's so it does not encode text at all: it is an unreadable binary blob, probably due to a system crash corrupting the file, simply delete the file `main.aux` @ab3001

Comment: oh but it's got nulls at the end of the document not the start (the aux file is read twice) if you delete the aux file and this error comes back you have something very strange happening, and you should add more details to your question @ab3001

Comment: Removing aux file didn't help. The current status is:
The project has several parts in different files that included into the main file using `\include` command.
On my local computer, I can compile each file separately, when I comment out the inclusion of other parts. The compilation output is not good, since some content is simply missing. When I compile all files, I get the same error.

On Overleaf platform I can compile only is I compile with TeX Live version 2021 (instead of 2023 or 2022) and remove all long tables (`longtblr`).

Comment: you can not write a sequence of null bytes from classic tex you can from luatex but not accidentally, in 99% of times such a sequence comes from a system crash that has trashed the filesystem at that point. do you really get no error before tex tries to read in the aux file and it is full of null? @ab3001

Comment: you need to remove the aux file before each test, then gradually move the `\end{document}` forwards to find the point at which it is being corrupted, then you should be able to show an example and ask people to debug

Comment: "do you really get no error before tex tries to read in the aux file and it is full of null?" I don't know at which point tex tries to read in the aux file. I am quite new to LaTex. I will try to gradually move the '\end{document}' forwards, as you proposed.

Comment: but you must know if  `No file main.ind. (./main.aux ! Text line contains an invalid character` is the first error reported,