# Memory settings with MacTeX 2012

Tags: texlive, mactex, texmf

Until now I had TeXLive 2011 installed and could successfully modify my memory settings using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24772/3735) with the TextWrangler approach to the question [Memory settings with MacTeX - Which texmf.cnf to modify](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24753/3735). After switching to MacTeX 2012 this doesn't work for me anymore. I already tried completely uninstalling all TeX-files and reinstalling only 2012, but that doesn't change anything.

Maybe this are some clues:

1. When I try to modify `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf` in TextWrangler I get [image: the message below], 
   but it lets me change the file anyway after clicking Unlock.
2. `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` runs just fine in the terminal, but I still get `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]`, when LaTeXing my document, though the `texmf.cnf`-file is definitely changed.

---

EDIT:

Well, up to a value `main_memory = 12000000` I am able to increase my memory by using [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27586/3735). Higher values don't seem to be possible. This solves my current problem. But as one is supposed to rather change the `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf` than `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` I'm still happy about any clues or even an answer regarding my original question.

Comment: Is it possible that you at some point ran `fmtutil` instead of `fmtutil-sys`? If so, you need to delete `~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var`.  I just increased the memory on a new TL 2012 using the same procedure, and it worked as advertised, so I don't think anything has changed in this respect between TL 2011 and 2012. And you *did* save the changed `.cnf` file, right? (I'm sure you did, but it never hurts to ask.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I never did that as I tried to follow your instructions to the mentioned question exactly. Nevertheless, I deleted all `~/Library/texlive/2011`-folders and to be sure also the `~/Library/texlive/2012/texmf-var`. The error still occurs.

Comment: And yes, if I open `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf` in any editor, I can see my modifications. They definitely seem to be saved.

Comment: When you compile a file that works, does the log file report the changed value of memory, or still the 300000?

Comment: It reports the original 3000000, not my changed number. I did another complete reinstall, this time using your emacs approach with terminal in case this is about TextWrangler. But the problem remains the same though the file displays my changes.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l $(kpsewhich texmf.cnf)` issued at the Terminal?

Comment: It is `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  591 28 Jul 19:44 /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf.cnf` I have no idea, what that means, though...