# Forest with ~500 nodes runs out of TeX memory

Tags: errors, miktex, forest, memory

When using `Forest` package to chart an organizational structure, I have to limit it to 4-5 hierarchy levels, as **both** `pdflatex` or `lualatex` throw an error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].`

The forest that fails contains approximately 500-600 nodes. There is only one forest per file.

I already tried to increase MikTex 2.9 (updated to the current) main memory by running

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=pdflatex
initexmf --dump=pdflatex
```

but the error is still there and the number 50,000 in the error message is still the same. Is there a similar INI file for `lualatex`?

**Q:** Are there any other methods that would allow to increase memory utilization allowed for `pdflatex` or `lualatex`? When they run, they do not exceed 43 MB and 75 MB respectively before they exit with the error.

I am not providing an MWE yet as 1) I would have to scramble data and it would become hard to read, and 2) it is unlikely anyone here is prepared to spend time sifting thru 500 nodes anyhow. Open to suggestions!

One of the answers here suggested a workaround of including

```
\tikzset{external/system call= {pdflatex -save-size=800000 
                               -pool-size=10000000 
                               -extra-mem-top=50000000 
                               -extra-mem-bot=10000000 
                               -main-memory=90000000 
                               \tikzexternalcheckshellescape 
                               -halt-on-error 
                               -interaction=batchmode
                               -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
```

but the error is still there.

Also tried to use command line option `--extra-mem-top=2000000` with no success.

Comment: luatex should use dynamic memory allocation and not use those settings, as far as I understand, do you get the same error with luatex?

Comment: Yes, pdflatex or lualatex give the same error: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].
`

Comment: Is this the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185153/39222? (Linked to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134597/39222.)

Comment: @cfr No, this question is different, as the linked applied to TexLive, but this applies to MikTex. However, I am now facing a ridiculous situation, where after minor changes (that mostly have to do with increased number of lines drawn between the Forest nodes) `lualatex` started throwing error messages on the smaller forests, but `pdflatex` compiles them fine!

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No solution yet, I had to limit the data structure before export to LaTeX instead. Maybe you should try to report this to Saso (Forest creator)?

Comment: @sinned If you are still looking for a solution, please see this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234215/37570

Comment: @ajeh please close this question as a dup (since you asked both and it is answered)