# Forest causing PdfLatex to run out of memory

Tags: errors, miktex, forest, memory

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185153/37570) almost a year ago but did not have much luck. MikTex's `PDFLaTeX` has been updated since, but the error is still there:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=50000].
```

Full source code at http://pastebin.com/XHazZ7Ux

Error log: http://pastebin.com/DtFcT9Cv

Same error with `LuaLatex`.

Hopefully this time some will be able to shed light on the limitation, why is it in place and what can be done to increase the amount of memory available to compilation.

Comment: Do you *really* think to typeset such a gigantic tree?

Comment: Yes, I really need to do that. But let me ask you, in the age of hundreds of GB of RAM is that really that audacious? (Especially when we are talking of what - 50K or 80K of RAM).

Comment: What's exhausted is the “save size”, that is the memory used to store values when TeX enters a new group. I don't know the exact implementation of `forest`, but probably it uses groups for drawing the subtrees, which means that you either exhaust the save size or the “nest size” because you open too many groups. LuaTeX uses dynamic memory allocation for the main memory, but it still follows TeX's model in some parts (the save size and the nest size among them). In TeX Live the nest size is set to 500.

Comment: I tried with LuaLaTeX on a Unix system with the command line `save_size=1000000 lualatex bigforest` (I removed the inessential `tabular` and left just the code for the tree); painfully slow, at the end I got `! Dimension too large.`. Lengths can't exceed 2^30sp, that is 5.75 meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved that by editing `\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\config\texmf-defaults.ini` and changing the line

```
save_size=1000000 ;;50000
```

Answer (score 5):

If I compile on my system with

```
save_size=1000000 lualatex bigforest
```

I get no `TeX capacity exceeded` error, at least until the

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@x 

l.4628 \end{forest}
```

error shows up. So one can certainly lift off the limitation on the save size (LuaTeX needs to allocate some special space for it, but it's extendable at run time). However the limitation that lengths mustn't exceed 2<sup>30</sup> scaled points, that is, about 5.75 meters (slightly less than 18.9 feet) can't be removed.

Comment: What would be the complete command line for that?

Comment: @ajeh I really don't know the equivalent for MiKTeX. However, the size error is fatal.

Comment: MikTex uses the same commands as TexLive. I tried `lualatex --shell-escape --save_size=1000000 --lualatex --bigforest chart.tex` but got the same error as previously.

Comment: @ajeh I doubt very much that egreg's copy of lualatex features a `--bigforest` option. egreg's file is `bigforest.tex`. Yours is `chart.tex`. So `save_size=1000000 lualatex chart` would be equivalent (adapted for MiKTeX).

Comment: Slap on the forehead smilie! Of course, it's a file name sans .tex extenstion. I should have figured it out. But anyhow, see my answer for the exact name of the config file below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the main culprit for the error is PGF/TikZ, which causes save stack buildup by mixing local and global assignments to `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y`.

As these two `\dimen` registers are used extensively in PGF's internal computations, it makes sense that larger trees, or longer documents in general, will exhaust the save stack.

The only solution I see is that someone goes through PGF/TikZ code and fixes the usage of these registers. They have 5313 occurrences in PGF/TikZ code; 590 of them are easily recognizable as assignments as they are followed by `=`. :-(

EDIT: Actually, and seriously. `\pgf@x` and `\pgf@y` are only assigned globally in a couple (about 50 easily recognizable) places in the entire PGF/TikZ. If those assignments could be fixed, maybe through the introduction of `\pgf@x@global` and `\pgf@y@global`, the task would actually be manageable (disregarding third party packages and user macros here...).

Comment: Good to hear from you Sašo, I really appreciate you looking into this!